# How to style an Ajax Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am calling a modal for editing purposes. using the following code, how can I set the css styling width height etc?

```js
// Open modal in AJAX callback
$("modal").dialog({
  modal: true,
  minHeight: 500,
  minWidth: 1200,
  maxWidth: 1200,
  maxHeight: 750
});
$('#manual-ajax').click(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  $.get(this.href, function(html) {
    $(html).appendTo('body').modal();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.modal.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.modal.min.css" />

<a rel="modal:open" class="btn-info btn-sm " href="{{ route('edit_deploy_time', $campaign_job->id) }}" id="manual-ajax"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Edit</a>
```

Comment: Is it the full code? I cannot see the html code for modal layout.

Comment: sorry it's old code , just noticed it is a plugin http://jquerymodal.com/

Comment: `$(html).appendTo('body').modal();`, the modal will be in your body, so just find it's id (relative to the plugin) ore one class it has, and you cans style it from a basic stylesheet or `<style>`

Answer (score 1):

you must use `modalClass` and `blockerClass` and `closeClass` for styling jquery-modal.

```
...
modalClass: "mymodal",
...
```

and style it:

```
<style>
    .mymodal {
        background: #ccc;
        border: solid 1px black;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok it was a simple styling setup:

```
.modal{}
```